# Cross domain issues getting Facebook Connect working

Tags: facebook, cross-domain

I'm having trouble setting up a pretty simple site that I want to use FB Connect.  Nothing crazy with popups, iframes, etc on my end, just have a FB login button on the page.  I'm getting a cross-domain error after following the instructions on [FB's tutorial](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect_Tutorial1)

**Error**:

> Permission denied for http://www.facebook.com (document.domain=http://facebook.com) to get property Location.href from `http://localhost:8080` (document.domain has not been set).

I have the **xd_receiver.htm** file set up and have verified that I can navigate to this via the path I set up using the Connect URL etc.  What's odd is that this works perfectly fine in Safari but not in Firefox.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, facebook has or will soon disable facebook connect.  it's possible that is your problem.

Comment: Silmaril - got a source for that? I'm pretty sure FBConnect is still going to be around

Comment: Ever get this figured out? I'm getting the same error, after a period of time where Facebook Connect was in fact working.  It's been a bit since I tested it, so I'm not sure what I changed (if anything) to break it...